# How to add score in Unity2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Firstly hi to all! I am just trying to learn unity from basics. I am trying to write a code, shortly explain, golds and bombs dropping from the upside and we are trying to catch.

But in my code, bombs are fully working well but coins not working. Just nothing happening when coins touch my character. Coins have to destroy themselves and they must add +10 to my score.

Comment: Hi CPrecius Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order for us to help you, can you share your code where you collect coins and show us what you have tried so far? so that we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated&Tested**

For a 2D game, add a BoxCollider2D and a Rigidbody2D onto your character's GameObject. Set the coin object's BoxCollider's isTrigger bool to true in the inspector.

Add this to your player/character script.

```
int score = 0;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText; //in Unity, drag a text component here.

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        score += 10;
        scoreText.text = score.toString();
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

For a 3D game, add a standard BoxCollider and a Rigidbody onto your character's GameObject. Set the coin object's BoxCollider's isTrigger bool to true in the inspector.

Add this to your player/character script:

```
int score = 0;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText; //in Unity, drag a text component here.

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag=="Coin")
    {
        score += 10;
        scoreText.text = score.toString();
        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks a lot!